# Sucesion Malabarista en python

Tags: python, while, condiciones, bucles

Tengo que crear un programa que le pida al usuario números naturales o `0` para terminar y por cada numero que ingrese el usuario, el programa deberá crear una sucesión malabarista y mostrarlos en pantalla.

A su vez, cuando el programa termine, deberá mostrar en pantalla cual fue el numero que genero la sucesión mas larga y la mas corta.

Esto es lo que hace la sucesión:

> si numero es par   => numero = numero^(1/2)
>   si numero es impar => numero = numero^(3/2)

Y la sucesion termina cuando numero = 1

Aqui el codigo:

```
numero = int(input('Ingrese un numero natural o 0 para terminar: '))
contador_max = 0
contador_min = 1

while numero != 0:
    num = numero
    contador = 0

    while num != 1:
        if num % 2 == 0 :
            num = int(num ** 0.5)
            print (num,end=' ')    
        else :
            num =int(num ** 1.5)
            print(num,end=' ')
        contador =+ 1

    if contador > contador_max:
        contador_max = contador
        maximo = numero
    if contador < contador_min:
        contador_min = contador
        minimo = numero
    print()
    numero = int(input('Ingrese un numero natural o 0 para terminar: '))
print('La sucesion mas larga se genero con el numero:',maximo)
print('La sucesion mas corta se genero con el numero:',minimo)
```

Todo esto debo hacerlo solamente usando `While, if, elif, else` y alguna otra que aparecen ahí en el código.

Como verán, mi problema ocurre cuando finalizo el programa, ya que me dice que la variable `minimo` no esta definida, y antes de ese error, la otra era que, cuando me decía cual numero genero la mas larga y la mas corta sucesión, me mostraba el mismo numero para ambas (el del máximo).

Comment: Hola Dark.R, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Quería felicitarte por tu primera pregunta pues, aunque es una tarea académica, no nos pides que te la resolvamos, sino que demuestras haberlo intentado por tí mismo (y de hecho estabas muy cerca de la solución). La pregunta está bien formulada y con toda la información necesaria para resolverse. Tienes mi +1.

Comment: Hola Dark! Bienvenido. Muy buena pregunta y estructura para ser la primera! Te comento que este sitio no es un foro. Aqui solo hacemos preguntas y respuestas, y no conversaciones ni hilos. Mira el [tour] para más info. un saludo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hay un par de errores en tu código.

- El valor de `contador_min` debería inicializarse a un número arbitrariamente grande. Tal como lo tienes, inicializado con 1, nunca va a cambiar ese valor ya que cualquier secuencia de "malabarismos" será más larga de 1. Es por eso que la variable `minimo` nunca es asignada y te da ese error. Para arreglarlo haz `contador_min=1000000` por ejemplo.
- Casi más importante (¡y más difícil de ver!) para incrementar el contador, en lugar de `contador += 1` has puesto `contador =+ 1`, que básicamente es lo mismo que `contador = +1`. Es decir, en vez de incrementar el contador ¡le asignas siempre el valor 1!

Corrigiendo ambos errores el programa ya funciona correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! , funciono perfecto y como recien estoy comenzando con python , no sabia el dato de += e =+  no eran lo mismo , y respecto a 'contador_min' , tienes mucha razon.

Comment: @Dark.R Quizás sea por evitar este tipo de confusiones que muchos pythonistas reniegan del operador `+=` y recomiendan usar `contador = contador + 1`. El "operador" `=+` con el que te confundiste no existe en realidad. Es un operador de asignación (`=`) seguido de un signo más, que se tomará como parte de la expresión a asignar.

Comment: @Dark.R y en la mayoria no solo python tiene esta caracteristicas , hay muchos mas